# Design pattern when you have multiple tasks with and without dependency on each other

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

for eg :
say you are loading an app

Where you have tasks like login task - which has no dependency
then say fetchUserData - which depends on login task
then say fetchUserHistory etc - which say depends on above 2 tasks
and say there are 10 more such tasks with cross dependencies

i know that I can simple do await async and run multiple independent etc parallely

but is there a generic way which is more neat and easy to add more tasks in future if required.

or is there a generic design pattern which does the same ?

Answer (score 1):

You can always take a quick look at [all design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) out there and figure out if there is one which matches your use-case (they're not that many).

In order to make this code scalable, you should design tasks and dependencies in an abstract way, a minimal sketch would be something like:

```java
interface Task {
    Result execute(Input input);
    List<Task> getDependencies();
}
```

Maybe [Mediator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/mediator) pattern can help here, and also if you're looking for an execution engine for those tasks, you should consider a [DAG-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph#Applications) scheduling process